# Is there a way to stream a torrent with web torrent to a video tag

Tags: javascript, html, torrent, webtorrent

This code is the code [on their website](https://webtorrent.io/intro) that downloads torrents

```js
const WebTorrent = require('webtorrent')

const client = new WebTorrent()

// Sintel, a free, Creative Commons movie
const torrentId = 'magnet:?'

client.add(torrentId, function (torrent) {
  // Torrents can contain many files. Let's use the .mp4 file
  const file = torrent.files.find(function (file) {
    return file.name.endsWith('.mp4')
  })

  // Display the file by adding it to the DOM.
  // Supports video, audio, image files, and more!
  file.appendTo('body')
})
```

Below this code is says

> Video and audio content can be streamed, i.e. playback will start before the full file is downloaded. Seeking works too – WebTorrent dynamically fetches the needed torrent pieces from the network on-demand.

I have searched the internet and not found a way to implement this streaming to video tag feature. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `I have searched the internet and not found a way to implement this streaming to video tag feature. Does anyone know how to do this?` Thats exactly what the code you've shown does.

Answer (score 1):

From their [docs](https://webtorrent.io/docs), use this method `file.renderTo('#video')`

```js
const client = new WebTorrent()

// Sintel, a free, Creative Commons movie
const torrentId = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:08ada5a7a6183aae1e09d831df6748d566095a10&dn=Sintel&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.empire-js.us%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2F&xs=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2Fsintel.torrent'

client.add(torrentId, function(torrent) {
  const file = torrent.files.find(function(file) {
    return file.name.endsWith('.mp4')
  })

  file.renderTo("#video", {
    autoplay: true,
    muted: true
  })
})
```

```css
video {
  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/webtorrent@latest/webtorrent.min.js"></script>
<video id="video"></video>
```